# Vibrate when UialertviewAppears iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, vibration

Currently i am playing a simple beep.mp3 file when alertview appears i am using avaudioplayer and set an indefinite loop to play beep until alert dismisses.Now i want to vibrate continuously when alertview appears with beep until user dismisses alert.how do i do this?

Answer (score -1):

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

([iPhone Dev Center link](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlaySystemSound))

Comment: i know this. but i need to vibrate continuously until alert dismissed